problem with routes in React Native and React Navigation
First of all, I apologize for my bad English, I'm not fluent and I'm using Google Translate
I want to create a route system like the one in the Twitter app, a system that has Drawer Routes , BottomTabRoutes and Stack Routes, where the tabBottomROutes are always visible and, when a stackRoute is opened, it overrides the DrawerRoutes
I've looked all over the internet and haven't found a good way to do this.
I'm using React Native with React Navigation and the current code is here (it is consuming a test API that I created)
If anyone knows a good way to clone Twitter or Reddit navigation, I'd be happy to know!
Note: I'm still learning React Native, even though I already have a good base in React.js, I have difficulty with things like this
Thank you
Here's my main screen:
MyApp Main Screen 
MyApp Drawer Navigation 
MyApp Profile Screen 
I want the navigation to look like this:
Twitter Main Screen 
Twitter Drawer Navigation 
Twitter Profile Screen 
